# (x86) How do I know which memory addresses not listed by the card given by Int 15/AX=E820h I can write in assembly?

Tags: assembly, memory, memory-management, x86, virtualbox

How do I know which memory addresses not listed by the card given by Int 15/AX=E820h I can write in assembly?

I can write to certain unlisted memory addresses and I cannot do it to others, for example:

I cannot write to memory address 4 273 995 773 which is not listed by Int 15/AX=E820h however I can write to memory address 4 294 967 297 which is not listed either

It is indicated on this [documentation](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/mem64mb.html) :  " The BIOS WILL NOT return a range description for the memory mapping of PCI devices, ISA Option ROM's, and ISA plug & play cards. This is because the OS has mechanisms available to detect them."

If this is what prevents writing to certain memory areas, how can I know this and know the exact locations where I cannot write because of PCI devices or others?

I specify that I am on boot sector and that I use Virtual Box.

I searched for the answer on the web and Stack Overflow without finding anything. I think my question is novel because others ask "are the segments that are not in this map belong to something like MMIO?" While I ask: "How do I know which memory addresses not listed by the card given by Int 15/AX=E820h I can write in assembly?"

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “Memory addresses I can read-write?”  Do you mean that when you write data to the address you can read it back?  Or do you mean that you get no fault if you do so?  I don't think there is any interface for what you are looking for.  All tables have various bits masked out and due to implementation details, there can always be undocumented extra bits of memory.

Comment: @fuz I removed the "read" I have no problem with reading the memory zones

When I want to write an 8 for example in a memory area sometimes I can and sometimes I can't, some memory areas won't let me do it and nothing happens

There is no way to know which memory addresses not listed by the card given by Int 15/AX=E820h I can write in assembly? No other way than to test if a memory area can be modified or not?

Comment: Exactly.  Note that it's generally a bad idea to overwrite random memory locations.  They may be used by firmware and modifying them may crash or even damage your computer (see also [this article on memory probing](https://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)#Manual_Probing)).  It is also possible that by accessing a memory location, you access a register of some device, changing its operation and possibly damaging the device.  Do not do that.

Comment: You can write on the memory ranges returned by the E820 map. Outside of those ranges, you must assume that reads and writes are not claimed by anything unless you know they are. For example, you may know that the 64KiBs at `0xa0000` are reclaimed by a graphics device. Or that some other ranges are MMIO to some PCI(e) devices that accept writes. You find out by enumerating the PCI(e) bus and accounting for legacy devices. Memory probing is dangerous, some DRAM is even used by the firmware. Most of the system memory is reported in the map anyway and most of the 64-bit address space is empty.